# Calculate Bounding Box Overlaps in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say we have two tensors of bounding box coordinates: `N`, with dimension [n, 4], and `K`, with dimension [k, 4]. Each row of each tensor represents the x1, y1, x2, and y2 of a bounding box.

Is there an efficient method in Tensorflow to produce an [n, k] matrix `M` where `M[i, j] = overlap(N[i, :], K[j, :])`? Ideally, `overlap` would be the Intersection-over-Union, but if it's simpler to use another method that would also work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/core/box_list_ops.py) of official object detection model has a function for calculating iou, see function `intersection` and `iou` for reference